# Как реализовать логику фильтра?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb

Есть три выпадающих списка.
Нужно сделать так, чтобы фильтровало по всем параметрам списка.

```
adsRouter.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  const city = req.query.city;
  const price = req.query.price;
  const date = req.query.date;
  const category = req.query.category
  const sectionParams = req.query.section
  const subsectionParams = req.query.subsection
  const page = req.query.page;
  const model = req.query.model;
  const pagesize = 25;

  const reqQuery = {
    city: city,
    category: category,
    section: sectionParams,
    subsection: subsectionParams,
    price: price,
    model: model,
    date: 'high',
  };

  const query = [
    {
      $match: { 
        category: { $eq: reqQuery.category },
      },
    },
    {
      $addFields: {
        __order: { $indexOfArray: [Reference.Status, '$status'] }
      }
    },
    {
      $sort: {
        __order: 1,
        ...(reqQuery.price ? { productPrice: reqQuery.price === 'high' ? -1 : 1 } : {}),
        ...(reqQuery.date ? { backendDate: reqQuery.date === 'high' ? -1 : 1 } : {}),
        updatedAt: -1
      }
    },
  ];
  if (reqQuery.city) {
    query[0].$match.city = { $eq: reqQuery.city };
  }
  if (reqQuery.section) {
    query[0].$match.section = { $eq: reqQuery.section };
  }
  if (reqQuery.subsection) {
    query[0].$match.subsection = { $eq: reqQuery.subsection };
  }
  if (reqQuery.model) {
    query[0].$match.fields = { $eq:  {mark:reqQuery.model} }; /// не срабатывает
  }  



  let result = []
  let pages;
  const items = await AdModel.aggregate([...query, { $skip: ((page || 1) - 1) * pagesize },{ $limit: pagesize }])

  if(items.length) {
    const countAds = await AdModel.aggregate([...query,{$count:'ads'}])
    pages = Math.ceil((Number(countAds[0].ads)/Number(pagesize)))
    result = items
  } 
  
  res.json([result, pages])
})
```

**Пример объявления**

```js
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "601c09722ed02e2c3c0653a5"
  },
  "img": [
    "1612450160628"
  ],
  "date": "04.02.2021",
  "backendDate": 1612449945036,
  "services": [
    "shares",
    "sales",
    "hots",
    "recommend",
    "runStroke",
    "banner"
  ],
  "viewsAll": 1,
  "viewsToday": 1,
  "lastViewDate": {
    "$date": "2021-02-04T14:45:45.036Z"
  },
  "section": "Легковые",
  "subsection": "BMW",
  "city": "Пенза",
  "productPrice": null,
  "priceAd": "305",
  "title": "BMW",
  "description": "Продам бмв в идеальном состоянии",
  "name": "Валерий",
  "phone": "+7812422112",
  "mail": "",
  "status": "gold",
  "category": "Авто",
  "fields": {
    "mark": "321",
    "engine": "2",
    "year": "2003",
    "color": "Черный",
    "milage": "200 тысяч",
    "enginePower": "150 л.с.",
    "countDoors": "4",
    "transmission": "Механика",
    "carState": "Отличное"
  },
  "__v": 0
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что мешает объединять условия в объекте параметров, а потом его передавать в find?

Comment: @Anatoly спасибо, завтра попробую

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Делаем тестовую модель

```js
// @ts-check
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = require('mongoose');

const Status = ['gold', 'silver', 'common'];
const Cities = ['Moscow', 'London', 'Paris'];
const Categories = ['Coffee', 'Tea'];
const Sections = ['One', 'Two'];
const Subsections = ['Four', 'Five'];

const schema = new Schema(
  {
    productPrice: { type: Number, required: true },
    backendDate: { type: Date, required: true },
    status: { type: String, enum: Status, required: true },
    city: { type: String, enum: Cities, required: true },
    category: { type: String, enum: Categories, required: true },
    section: { type: String, enum: Sections, required: true },
    subsection: { type: String, enum: Subsections, required: true },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
    autoIndex: true,
    autoCreate: true
  }
);

module.exports = {
  Reference: {
    Status,
    Cities,
    Categories,
    Sections,
    Subsections,
  },
  AdModel: mongoose.model('AdModel', schema)
};
```

#### Делаем тестовую заливку данных

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { AdModel, Reference } = require('./model');

(async () => {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(
      'mongodb://localhost:27017/test?readPreference=primary&appname=MongoDB%20Compass%20Community&ssl=false',
      { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }
    );

    AdModel.collection.drop();

    let count = 1000;
    while (--count >= 0) {
      await AdModel.create({
        productPrice: randomNumber(1000000),
        backendDate: randomDate(),
        status: Reference.Status[randomNumber(Reference.Status.length)],
        city: Reference.Cities[randomNumber(Reference.Cities.length)],
        category: Reference.Categories[randomNumber(Reference.Categories.length)],
        section: Reference.Sections[randomNumber(Reference.Sections.length)],
        subsection: Reference.Subsections[randomNumber(Reference.Subsections.length)],
      });
    }

    await mongoose.disconnect();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();

/**
 * @param {number} min
 * @param {number} [max]
 * @returns {number}
 */
function randomNumber(min = 0, max) {
  if (max === null || max === undefined) {
    max = min; min = 0;
  }
  return Math.trunc(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}

function randomDate(start = new Date(2000, 0, 1), end = new Date()) {
  return new Date(start.getTime() + Math.random() * (end.getTime() - start.getTime()));
}
```

### Забираем все данные одним запросом

```
// @ts-check
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { AdModel, Reference } = require('./model');

(async () => {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(
      'mongodb://localhost:27017/test?readPreference=primary&appname=MongoDB%20Compass%20Community&ssl=false',
      { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }
    );

    const reqQuery = {
      city: Reference.Cities[0],
      subsection: Reference.Subsections[0],
      price: 'high',
      date: 'high',
    };

    const page = randomNumber(10);

    const pagesize = 25;

    const query = [
      {
        $match: {}
      },
      {
        $addFields: {
          __order: { $indexOfArray: [Reference.Status, '$status'] }
        }
      },
      {
        $sort: {
          __order: 1,
          ...(reqQuery.price ? { productPrice: reqQuery.price === 'high' ? -1 : 1 } : {}),
          ...(reqQuery.date ? { backendDate: reqQuery.date === 'high' ? -1 : 1 } : {}),
          updatedAt: -1
        }
      },
      { $skip: ((page || 1) - 1) * pagesize },
      { $limit: pagesize }
    ];
    if (reqQuery.city) {
      query[0].$match.city = { $eq: reqQuery.city };
    }
    if (reqQuery.category) {
      query[0].$match.category = { $eq: reqQuery.category };
    }
    if (reqQuery.section) {
      query[0].$match.section = { $eq: reqQuery.section };
    }
    if (reqQuery.subsection) {
      query[0].$match.subsection = { $eq: reqQuery.subsection };
    }

    const items = await AdModel.aggregate(query);
    console.log(items);
    console.log(items.length);


    await mongoose.disconnect();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

---

*Есть вещи, которые я никогда не смогу понять, одна из них - использование mongodb (я бы мог добавить "там, где её лучше не использовать", но нет).*

Comment: Исправил, спасибо. Вроде все получилось,но сортировка по цене и дате не корректно работает. И пришлось еще раз вызывать метод find и разбить на массивы,что-бы узнать сколько всего страниц у категории.

Comment: 1) у меня на тестовых данных сортировка работает корректно, попробуйте :) возможно ваш кейс работает не так, как ожидалось, из-за того, что у вас атрибуты имеют другой тип данных...

Comment: 2) нащот find и "разбить на массивы". представьте, что вы пилите большую доску объявлений (шучу). представьте, что у вас десятки миллионов объявлений. и вот в этой ситуации вы поднимаете **все** объявления из базы только для того, чтобы посчитать пагинацию. даже если вы будете получать только идентификаторы без остальных данных, это - невероятнейший оверхед. вам нужно либо уходить от пагинаций к выбору следующей страницы, либо разбираться в том как в mongodb можно извлечь данные для пагинации агрегированным запросом, либо уходить в реляционную БД

Comment: Да, у меня данные цены и даты в типе  String.

Comment: может, перевести их в формат, адекватный назначению этих данных? :)

Comment: @nörbörnën А в чем собственно вопрос ? Я с монго не знаком и не знаю какие там есть способы узнать сколько записей в категории (если речь об этом) И да, даже в реляционках я стараюсь избегать пагинации всеми средствами.

Comment: @Mike вот ты, безусловно, эксперт. скажи, с такими фильтрами, сортировками, пагинацией, не лучше ли использовать postgresql? я думаю, что Ihor выбрал не тот инструмент под задачу

Comment: @nörbörnën Ну я всем предлагаю читать статью https://habr.com/ru/post/231213/  данные тут выглядят действительно слишком структурированно для noSQL. А вот имеет ли в принципе право на жизнь такое решение глядя только на этот пример я не могу сказать. в принципе в монге то же есть свои средства поиска. например эластик в ней обычно хранит данные и он быстро ищет вообще в куче разрезов. вопрос в том правильно ли эти средства используются тут. Кстати для реляционок поиск по множеству параметров то же составляет проблему, индексы на все поля не построишь... приходится выкручиваться

Comment: Я вот смотрю в монге есть функция count, на вскидку не могу сказать насколько она подходит для подсчета с массой условий и как монга справится с задачей. Но если справится - то вроде как и данные для подсчета вытягивать не надо. так что тут вопрос правилен ли подход ТС к решению данной мелкой задачи с пагинацией, может есть другие пути.

Comment: @nörbörnën Не знаешь почему может не сработать `query[0].$match.fields = { $eq:  {mark:reqQuery.model} };`

Comment: @IhorStoner как я могу это знать ничего не зная о твоей структуре данных?

Comment: @nörbörnën Я ниже прикрепил сразу. Получается `"fields": {"mark": "123"}`

Comment: @IhorStoner я так-то монгу не особо знаю, попробуй в лоб: `query[0].$match['fields.mark'] = { $eq:  reqQuery.model }` или `query[0].$match.fields.mark = { $eq:  reqQuery.model }`